# How to get the input element triggering the jQuery autocomplete widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-widgets

I have several input fields that are enhanced with jQuery auto-complete functionality. How to get the corresponding input field when a select event is triggered?

```
<input name="1" value="">
<input name="2" value="">
<input name="3" value="">

$('input[type=text]').autocomplete({
    source: 'suggestions.php',
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // here I need the input element that have triggered the event
    }
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using `$(this)`

```
$('input[type=text]').autocomplete({
    source: 'suggestions.php',
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // here I need the input element that have triggered the event
        alert($(this).attr('name'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it! I was trying $(this).name wondering why it is undefined. :)

Answer (score 36):

I was using an anonymous function for the `source` param, and `$(this)` inside it referenced the funcion, not the element that was triggering it. I had to use `$(this.element)`.

The final code ended similar to this *(I simplified it for demo purposes)*:

```
$( ".regionsAutocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){

        //The next line is the important one for this example
        var input = this.element;
        $(input).css('color','red');

        var data = {'foo':'bar'};
        $.ajax({
            'url': ajaxurl,
            'data': data,
            'method': "POST",
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed too. It is particularly useful when you want to pass the autocomplete input field's attribute(s) as parameters to your target lookup script.

Comment: The queried value actually resides in `request.term`. At least I use this all the time.

Comment: Good support, by the way where is the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$(this)` or `event.target`.

Then you can get the name using `$(this).prop('name')` or `event.target.name`.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ycrdm/1)

Comment: +1 For the event.target. Was a bit skeptical about using $(this) (closure and such). But both work and event.target is new information for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(this)`

```
 select: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).attr('name');
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell for this example, you wouldn't need the `$()`. `this` would work just fine since name is a defined attribute.

`this.name`