# Get index for selected div tag

Tags: jquery, ajax

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/p8hu7qnh/2/) is my code for multiple dynamic field. After inserted the fields, the `<div>` will become like this.

```
<div id="buildyourform">
    <div id="field1">
        <!--text fields go here -->
    </div>

    <div id="field2">
        <!--text fields go here -->
    </div>

    <div id="field3">
        <!--text fields go here -->
    </div>

    <div id="field4,5,6,7.....">
        <!--text fields go here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now,I have to use jquery `index()` to catch each `<div>` text field of part no. But it only returns the `first div tag,0` to me. How do I retrieve the other index/field?Below is my ajax and jquery to retrieve the data.

```
$(".partNumber").autocomplete({         
    minLength:1,
    source: 'readPart.php',
     select: function(event, ui){
        var selected = ui.item.value;
        $.ajax({                        
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_partDetails.php",
            data:'erfq_partNo='+selected,
            complete: function(response){   
                var index = $("#buildyourform div").index();
                alert(index);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I have tried this as well but I do not iterate the whole text field again and again and I just want to get the selected text field value only.

```
$('#buildyourform div').each(function(index){
    alert(index);
});
```

Here is the example output that I want.
[image]

Comment: I don't get your problem, what text field value are you talking about?

Comment: The dynamic text fields consist of auto complete function. Once the user has selected the part no, the description and price will be shown automatically. So I don't want to iterate over again and again.

Comment: @Sollo Are you after one value from each row, like part number? Or is it part number, description, and price?

Comment: Yes, it is one value from each row.[This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584046/get-index-for-selected-div-tag/33584105?noredirect=1#comment54945518_33584105)  almost solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen here: [How to get the input element triggering the jQuery autocomplete widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808854/how-to-get-the-input-element-triggering-the-jquery-autocomplete-widget), I think you can do something like this:

```
$(".partNumber").autocomplete({         
    minLength:1,
    source: 'readPart.php',
     select: function(event, ui){
        var selected = ui.item.value;
        var index = $(this).parent().index();
        alert(index);
        $.ajax({                        
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_partDetails.php",
            data:'erfq_partNo='+selected,
            complete: function(response){   
                //Do your code here
            }
        });
    }
});
```

EDIT: I just realize you're using jQuery autocomplete which helps me a lot to help you..

Comment: I think what I need cannot use `.each()` function because it consists of auto complete function in my program. Once I selected the value, the other text field will be changed accordingly.

Comment: Edited. Hope it helps

Comment: It returns no result(-1) even I try to edit your code to `$("#buildyourform div").find('input[value="'+selected+'"]').index();`

Comment: I have tried your edited answer. the index works well if I place it under the `select: function(event, ui){` but it will not work when I place it under complete function.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me to solve this problem. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the second param of each's inner function

```
$('#buildyourform div').each(function(index, obj){
    if ($(obj).attr("id") === 'userSelection') {
        alert(index);
        return false; // to break each
    }
});
```

**This example follows the documentation in:**

[JQuery each function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't want to iterate the whole div tag over again and again. If the user has entered `textfield2`, the alert message only will show index=1

Comment: I have added a new version of my answer.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I just added the sample output picture, you may take a look on it. My part no. text field ID is using `count`, but this creates problem to me. You may take a look at [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p8hu7qnh/2/)